# Как правильно создать связи в ember store, и получить данные из store в контроллере

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Добрый день. Есть такая проблема. Есть модель ember  - **orders**, она должна прийти из бекенда, но в этой модели должно быть поле **statuses**, которое формируется на фронте из модели **statuses**.

Как сформировать модель так, что бы она получала данные из бэка, а часть данных из фронта.

*routers/orders/new.js*

```
model: function(params) {

    var store = this.get('store');

    let blogPost = store.createRecord('dealer-statuses', [
        {id:'FindExecutor', text: "purpose of courier"},
         ....
        {id:9, text: "Removed"}
    ]);

    return store.query('orders', {});
}
```

*model/statuses.js*

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  count: DS.attr(),
  text: DS.attr(),
});
```

*model/orders.js*

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
     statuses: DS.belongsTo('dealer-statuses'),
     text: DS.attr()

});
```

И как получить данные допустим в контроллере. Делаю по клику action :

```
actions: {

    test: function () {
        debugger;
        this.get('store').query('orders', {}).then(function() {
                console.log('test')
        })
    }
 }

Но получаю ошибку
```

> Cannot read property 'type' of null

Адаптер ( пока тестовые данные):

```
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
query(store, type, query) {

    var service = this.get('service');
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        var data = {
                    "data": [ {
                        "type": "orders",
                        "id": "1",
                        "attributes": {
                            text: 1

                        }
                    }]
                };
        resolve(data);
    });
}
```

});